# Not able to drop or truncate the table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am not able to drop or truncate my table. However, i am successfully able to delete the rows from the table.

Whenever i try to drop or truncate my session goes in hanged state and i have to kill the session manually.

FYI. There is also a trigger associated with my table on before delete. I am also not able to disable that trigger.

Hoping, my question is clear. Please also suggest if some more information i need to provide.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: check for you permission .. (grant)

Comment: Maybe it's locked by another user? You need exclusive access to the table for truncate, drop etc..

Comment: @scaisEdge i have checked there is no issue of permissions. If there is issue of permission then i will get the error regarding grants not my session will hang. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @ammoQ i have checked in v$locked_objects not able to find any lock.

Comment: @Tajinder   correct .. then be sure the table is not locked .. by some others (insert, update, delete... )

Comment: @scaisEdge Not able to find my object_id in locked_objects. Please suggest if there is some other method.

Comment: @Tajinder why you are not able to disable the trigger ? what error give you ?

Comment: Check your filesystem, maybe it's full; in that case, Oracle can't write redo logs and blocks.

Comment: @Moudiz Sorry, this is what i am not able to understand. That's why i have mentioned that i am also not able to disable my trigger.

Comment: Triggers prevent neither `truncate` nor `drop`, they are not the reason of your problems.

Comment: @ammoQ yes, you are right. can you please suggest something on why i am not able to drop or disable my trigger.

Comment: Have you checked the file system as suggested?

Comment: @Tajinder how to know why the trigger is not disabling ? there is no error or any info.  run this ALTER TRIGGER trg_example DISABLE; is it hanging ?

Comment: @Moudiz yes disabling trigger hanging my session.

Comment: If you check and wait for some more time, yu will definitely get a Resource Busy error from Oracle side.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have complete info on whats going on but start by running this query in your session , if it give you result then there is a lock

```
  SELECT a.SESSION_ID, B.Owner, B.Object_Name, A.Oracle_Username, A.OS_User_Name  
FROM V$Locked_Object A, All_Objects B
WHERE A.Object_ID = B.Object_ID
```

try to release the lock and understand ow the lock happened maybe the trigger is executing something without commit ?

Note that you should run the above query when you are trying to truncate the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried your query after running truncate command. yes, i am getting row with my table name. Please suggest what to do now.

Comment: @Tajinder I edit my answer and i added session id , the query will tell you who is locking the table ,  what is the OS_USERNAME ? this will tell you the one who locked the table , then try know what he was executing , if he is making and DML changes (update , insert , delete) without commit , then thats why you have a lock. run a commit in his session and it will release the lock

Comment: Lock i am getting is due to my truncate command. can you please explain why i am successfully able to delete the rows from table, but not able to truncate the table. Thanks for your time.

Comment: when you have deleted the data , did you run commit ? can you run the delete from another session ? @Tajinder

Comment: yes, i run commit and delete is successful. i am running delete and truncate on the same session.

Comment: @Tajinder can you please do this ? delete all the data and commit, make sure the table is empty , run the above query to make sure NO LOCK is happening . then trucnate the table.

Comment: already done before posting the question. faced ist time such issue, sorry if not able to explain

Comment: @Tajinder run this query it will give the size of tablespace , are they full ?

select TABLESPACE_NAME "Tablspace",  
 FILE_NAME "Filename",  
 BYTES/1024/1024 "Size MB", 
 MAXBYTES/1024/1024 "Maximum Size MB", 
 AUTOEXTENSIBLE "Autoextensible"
from SYS.DBA_DATA_FILES